# Open page in home iFrame from external source

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I'm sorry guys, but I'm having some troubles by making a simple website dealing `iframes`.
I'm making a simple site with an `iframe`:

```
<iframe id = "FRM001" style = "position: absolute; z-index: 2; border: none; ...;"  
       src = "Folder/PM0000A.html"></iframe>
```

So far, so good.
Here's my trouble: Let's say `Google` links `PM0000A.html` on a research result (or I double click `PM0000A.html` on the folder of my project in my computer). How does the browser then open that page inside the `iframe` from the original `Home Page`?

I just need some help for this task, nothing else. And, unfortunately, I don't find the solution for this. Every search I do on the web regarding this matter links me to open pages in `iframes` and that's not exactly what I need.

Thanks.

Comment: `PM0000A.html` needs to run a script that checks if `parent === top` (i.e. if it isn't inside an iframe) and if so, redirect to the home page, providing itself as parameter. Like `if (parent === top) location = "//domain.com?show=" + location`

Comment: @ChrisG, thanks for the tip. I will try your suggestion.

Comment: @ChrisG, could you provide a better example? I'm getting the part of opening the home page, but your script is filling the `iFrame` with the home page itself.

Comment: How does the homepage set the iframe's `src`? Please add relevant code to the question. Nothing in my one line of example script fills anything, as far as I can tell.

Comment: @ChrisG, the task you asked for is already on my original question. Then, I created an `onLoad` function on `PM0000A.html` like you said: `if (parent === top) {location = "../Home.html?show=" + location}`. This opens `Home Page` alright. But fills the `iFrame` with the `Home Page` itself.

Comment: I didn't give you complete step-by-step instructions, I just told you the basic idea. You still need to extract the `location` parameter from the URL, then set the iframe's `src` to it. When you say you set `src` in the question, you're pointing to a hardcoded `src`; how is that ever supposed to show the actual document unless you change it accordingly?

Comment: @ChrisG, I know that!! I knew I had to define somewhere where the page was suppose to load (on the frame). I just don't get why the page loads itself precisely on that frame. But you helped me very much by just opening the page. I will figure this bug out! :)